# Zimbra relay local email

Tags: zimbra

I have two mail servers that share the same domain name how do I make zimbra relay email who isn't in the zimbra directory to the other email server

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is a split domain situation. This is [well documented on the Zimbra wiki](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Split_Domain). What you want is the following:

- By default all e-mail to `example.org` is routed to Zimbra.
- If the recipient for `example.org`, for example `foo@example.org` does *not* exist in Zimbra, it must be routed to the other mail system.
- If it exists on the other mail system, fine. If it does not exist, then inform the sender.

Basically the commands you need in your Zimbra are the following:

`$ zmprov md example.org zimbraMailCatchAllAddress @example.org
$ zmprov md example.org zimbraMailCatchAllForwardingAddress @example.org
$ zmprov md example.org zimbraMailTransport smtp:the-other-mail-server.example.org`

Comment: Mails are stuck in queue it's not delivering

Answer (score 1):

To move mail from one server to the other you will need to set up a per email transport in your transport table. Assuming that the transport table is set up in this manner: `transport_maps = /etc/postfix/transport` , you would add in a line for each email `user@domain.tld  transport:[nexthop]`

So you would probably use something like

`user1@example.com   smtp:[192.168.1.2]`

This will send user1's email via smtp to 192.168.1.2 (or a domain) without looking up the MX server, which may point back to your original server.

You would then run `postmap /etc/postfix/transport` which will generate the DB file, and reload postfix.

Answer (score -1):

Server recieving mail for ALL addresses that doesn't even exist, - is fast becoming spam target. So, better to check address existance before accepting mail.

If the second mail server is also Zimbra, you could use the built-in Zimbra capability to spread of users across the mail servers in the same domain - "Zimbra Multi-Server Installation".